# Why am I getting RE for this code on Google Code Jam?

Tags: python

I wrote the following code and tried to submit it. It works perfectly on my own machine but when I try to test run it on their website, it says there was a runtime error. This is not the first question where I have encountered this but the second. This is not a logical error but something wrong with the syntax or how I am taking the inputs maybe. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

[Screenshot of code with problem statement from the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YI7F8.png)

Here's the code if you couldn't see the picture:

```
t = int(input().strip())
for i in range(1, t+1):
    n = int(input().strip())
    p = input().strip()
    res = ""
    for c in p:
        if c == 'E':
            res += 'S'
        else:
            res += 'E'
    print(f"Case #{i}: {res}")
```

Comment: Provide the error message.

Comment: @Unapiedra the website does not show one that's the problem...

Comment: Is it mandatory to print?

Comment: @alan.elkin it got solved. Their python version did not support f-strings that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
t = int(input().strip())
for i in range(1, t+1):
    n = int(input().strip())
    p = input().strip()
    res = ""
    for c in p:
        if c == 'E':
            res += 'S'
        else:
            res += 'E'
    print("Case #{}: {}".format(i, res))
```

I'm guessing whatever version google runs is less than 3.6 when f-strings were introduced; verified this works.